# python library to connect to apns do not have a place to add passphrase APNSWrapper, pyapns ( note: i am not asking how to bypass passphrase)

Tags: python, apple-push-notifications, passphrase

when i write a python script to connect to APNS and send push notifications jsut like the sample script

https://code.google.com/p/apns-python-wrapper/wiki/APNSWrapperOverview

I do not find a place to pass it the PEM passphrase.

Not i was able to manage by removing the need of passphrase but ideally i want to give it the passphrase in the code rather than on command line prompt

anybody dealt with this ?

deviceToken = 'Qun\xaa\xd4R\x11zu\x07\x04\x9dG\xe6\x96j&\x95Y\x9d\x91~\xcc`z\n\x88O\xc0\x9c\xf6\xca'

```
# create wrapper
wrapper = APNSNotificationWrapper('iphone_cert.pem', True)

# create message
message = APNSNotification()
message.token(deviceToken)
message.badge(5)

# add message to tuple and send it to APNS server
wrapper.append(message)
wrapper.notify()
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of                                            "iphone push notifications passphrase issue (pyAPns) "

Comment: I has used that that issue says ..and i am able to bypass the need of passphrase. But i want to secure my application and i want to know "how to add passphrase" in the code rather than bypass it ! please remove it as a duplicate of that issue .... stackexchange is becoming really difficult

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/apns-python-wrapper/issues/detail?id=19&thanks=19&ts=1406818932

Comment: FOlKS!!! who marked it as duplicates ..please read!!!!